# Spring and MyBatis cannot find bean via MapperScannerConfigurer if interface inside .jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using `Spring 3.2.0` in a legacy project with `Mybatis 3.3.0` and `Mybatis Spring 1.2.3.`

I have several projects that use this technology and they need to have similar new code added to a library that will allow me to interact with an outside system, and during this interaction I need to call several methods in the database in this new code.

I created an interface and put it in a package, say:

```
com.mycompany.myapp.dao.MyNewService
```

That interface has a few methods.  All of those are defined in a `Mybatis` mapper file, `MyNewService.xml` in that *same* package path.

I create a .jar file of all this code.

In my main application, I added a dependency to this .jar file and it ends up inside of `WEB-INF\lib\MyHelpers.jar`

In that application, I have a root application context spring file and I attempt to use a `mybatis MapperScannerConfigurer` to find this new bean/service via:

```
<!--scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mycompany.myapp.dao" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName"
      value="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I run this code, it appears that it cannot find this service in that package path which I know is in `WEB-INF\lib\MyHelpers.jar`.

The application produces a warning on startup:

```
WARN (ClassPathMapperScanner.java:167) - No MyBatis mapper was 
found in '[com.mycompany.myapp.dao]' package. 
Please check your configuration.
```

The code later fails during dependency injection with a massive stacktrace which essentially says:

> 2017-03-08 15:38:39,625 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR 
>   (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:466) - Context
>   initialization failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'orderDetailsController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.dao.MyNewService
>   com.mycompany.otherapp.controller.OrderDetailsController.myNewService
>   ; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [com.mycompany.myapp.dao.MyNewService ] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

If I dig into that Mybatis code, its simply not finding the resource from the package path inside that .jar when it's using some ResourceResolver code.  *IF* I move my code into my project directly rather than adding the .jar dependency, the code works fine without error.

The concern of course is that I have to put this same code across *six* projects, so I thought I'd have it in this .jar file and use the `MapperScannerConfigurer`.  We use that in all the projects but all the .xml is within the applications `WEB-INF\classes` when deployed, it is *not* inside a .jar file within `WEB-INF\lib`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?  In summary, it would be akin to:

1. Making a file called `Model.jar` based on `Mybatis` interfaces and .xml mapper files
2. Adding this as a dependency that appears in `WEB-INF\lib`
3. configuring the main spring applicationContext file using the syntax I have above.

If you need more clarification, I can certainly add it.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that MyHelpers.jar is not part of your classpath. This is a configuration issue. If you are using maven then just add this jar as a dependency if not the you need to fix it manually by adding this jar to your classpath.

Comment: The MyHelpers.jar is in WEB-INF\lib, but the Spring resource reader does not appear to read definitions from inside of this.  If it's in WEB-INF\classes, it works fine.

If I *don't* use MapperScannerConfigurer and create an implementation class that implements the interface and extends SqlSessionDaoSupport, then configure Spring to inject a sqlsession into that, it works fine.  It's just the MapperScannerConfigurer does not appear to see it.

Comment: I also think the jar content is not in the classpath on runtime, even though it may be on compile time, in your IDE. Check it is well exported when building, present in appropriate location in deployed WAR. You can verify more simply by referencing a class provided by the JAR and expect ClassNotFoundException. It is legacy project, then maybe not using Maven or any building tool that would handle this dependency issue?

Comment: As a test, a made a junit test class, and moved part of the code to another project.  I made the main project depend on this project's output.  When it ran, it had -classpath "c:\dev\projects\MyProject\classes;..." and worked fine.  Then I changed it so it would depend on the output of the JAR from the second project, i.e. C:\dev\projects\MyProject\deploy\MyLibrary.jar and it did't run.  ClassPathMapper scanner reported: "No MyBatis mapper was found in '[package path]' and then a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException was thrown for not being able to find an @Autowire bean for the test.